# When I try to run the program to calculate payment and total intrest I get "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub TxtAmt_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtAmt.Enter
    Dim Amount As Integer
    For index As Integer = 2 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        Amount += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value)

        'if you have the other column to get the result you  could add a new one like these above (just change Cells(2) to the one you added)
    Next

    Dim tcredit As Decimal = 0
    tcredit = Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value)
    Dim total As Double = 0
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 2 Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            total = total + Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        Next
        total = total + TxtAmt.Text
        Dim row As String() = New String() {Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "Payments", TxtVoucher.Text, TxtAmt.Text, (Convert.ToString(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value - total)), CmboInvoc.Text}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    Else
        Dim row As String() = New String() {Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "Payments", TxtVoucher.Text, TxtAmt.Text, (Convert.ToString(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value - TxtAmt.Text)), CmboInvoc.Text}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        total = TxtAmt.Text
    End If

    TxtDbit.Text = total
    TxtBalnc.Text = (tcredit) - Convert.ToDecimal(TxtDbit.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! The errormessage is pretty clear, in one of your conversions the input string is empty and error is thrown. Debug the code to see which line/cell is giving you the error. There is no way for us to help you, we can not know what data is in those cells.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`: it will help you to determine when you're doing something wrong while you're typing. Also, you really don't need (or want) to convert a Date type to string: use the `Format` property to present a Date in a specific format. You need to convert the values read from the TextBoxes, instead.

Comment: You have this code in the `Enter` event which executes when you "enter" the control. At that point, the textbox is empty or "" and you're trying to convert this to a Type Double. Move this code to an event that allows a little more control on when it's executed or put it some error handling to keep this from trying to store an invalid result into a specific type. [Double.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It would be better practice to make use of [DataTable Column Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8) and [DataTable.Compute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed up the code with lots of .TryParse methods. It will now work with Option Strict On.

```
Private Sub TxtAmt_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtAmt.Enter
    Dim Amount As Integer
    For index As Integer = 2 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        Dim AmountToAdd As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value.ToString, AmountToAdd)
        Amount += AmountToAdd
    Next

    Dim tcredit As Decimal
    Decimal.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString, tcredit)
    Dim total As Double = 0
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 2 Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            Dim rowTotal As Double
            Double.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString, rowTotal)
            total += rowTotal
        Next
        Dim AmountFromTextBox As Double
        Double.TryParse(TxtAmt.Text, AmountFromTextBox)
        total += AmountFromTextBox
        Dim row As String() = New String() {Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "Payments", TxtVoucher.Text, TxtAmt.Text, (Convert.ToString(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value - total)), CmboInvoc.Text}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    Else
        Dim row As String() = New String() {Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "Payments", TxtVoucher.Text, TxtAmt.Text, (Convert.ToString(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value - TxtAmt.Text)), CmboInvoc.Text}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        Dim AmountFromTextBox As Double
        Double.TryParse(TxtAmt.Text, AmountFromTextBox)
        total = AmountFromTextBox
    End If

    TxtDbit.Text = total.ToString
    TxtBalnc.Text = (tcredit - Convert.ToDecimal(TxtDbit.Text)).ToString

End Sub
```